# Sorted dynamic list is read only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a dynamic list that I try to sort then change the id based on the new sort order:

```
foreach (Case c in cases)
{
    bool edit = true;

    if (c.IsLocked.HasValue)
        edit = !c.IsLocked.Value;

    eventList.Add(new {
        id = row.ToString(),
        realid = "c" + c.CaseID.ToString(),
        title = c.CaseTitle + "-" + c.Customer.CustomerDescription,
        start = ResolveStartDate(StartDate(c.Schedule.DateFrom.Value.AddSeconds(row))),
        end = ResolveEndDate(StartDate(c.Schedule.DateFrom.Value), c.Schedule.Hours.Value),
        description = c.CaseDescription,
        allDay = false,
        resource = c.Schedule.EmployeID.ToString(),
        editable = edit,
        color = ColorConversion.HexConverter(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.Color.Value))
    });

    row++;

}

var sortedList = eventList.OrderBy(p => p.title);

for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count(); ++i)
{
    sortedList.ElementAt(i).id = i.ToString();
}
```

But it crashes on  `sortedList.ElementAt(i).id = i.ToString();` stating that it is read only?

> Property or indexer `<>f__AnonymousType4<string, string,string,string,string,string,bool,string,bool,string>.id` cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

How can I change the ids?

Thanks

Comment: You could try to copy the sorted list to a new list instance

Comment: What type is `.id`? If this is a property with only get accessor, you can't set it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned you cannot update an anonymous type,  however you can modify your process to use one query that orders the items first and includes the index of the item as a parameter to the `Select`:

```
var query = cases.OrderBy(c => c.CaseTitle + "-" + c.Customer.CustomerDescription)
                 .Select( (c, i) =>
                    new {
                            id = i.ToString(),
                            realid = "c" + c.CaseID.ToString(),
                            title = c.CaseTitle + "-" + c.Customer.CustomerDescription,
                            start = ResolveStartDate(StartDate(c.Schedule.DateFrom.Value.AddSeconds(i))),
                            end = ResolveEndDate(StartDate(c.Schedule.DateFrom.Value), c.Schedule.Hours.Value),
                            description = c.CaseDescription,
                            allDay = false,
                            resource = c.Schedule.EmployeID.ToString(),
                            editable = c.IsLocked.HasValue ? !c.IsLocked.Value : true ,
                            color = ColorConversion.HexConverter(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(c.Color.Value))
                        }
                   );
```

Comment: +1 You posted the exact solution I was just getting ready to post.  I already had it written when I saw a new answer was posted. :)